# TinyMce view html issue when using a conditional html

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, tinymce

When I view source of the `tiny-mce` plugin and add the following code, next time when I click button to see HTML source `code` it gives me following error.

### HTML

```
<h3><!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--> <!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="276">
</w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]--></h3>
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
<p>Rest of the body</p>
```

### Error

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'insertNode' on 'Range': The node to be inserted contains a 'SPAN' node, which may not be inserted here.
```

### Already tried

When i add an empty container just like this, it fixes the problem.

```
<p></p>    
 <h3><!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--> <!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="276">
</w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]--></h3>
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
<p>Rest of the body</p>
```

Comment: when you say `i added following code` , do you mean you updated the `tinymce` plugin source code ?

Comment: No, The HTML code in source.

Comment: Updated the html code to be inserted in the tiny-mce source html.

Comment: My advice is never edit the source code/lib of a js plugin, unless you really know what your doing, it pretty tough to fix any issues like this if you alter the code. if at all you need some functionality of the plugin to be altered, try writing your own script,which should override the existing function of the plugin .

Comment: No, i have not edited any code of the plugin; When you write somthing in the tinymce; and crosponding html code is generated which we can view.

Comment: oh more like a code, which could be embedded anywhere in web ? my mistake, i probably misunderstood your coment.